# Can't seem to delete indices on my 3-node elasticsearch cluster

Tags: elasticsearch

A very simple three node unicast cluster (all are master-eligible), with about 200 indices, created by a script.

When I do DELETE /* on one of the nodes (probably not the master one) I see the indices (physical folders in /data) being deleted, they decrease in number by about 10, and I see them disappearing from the list. But after a few seconds, they start filling up again, being recreated... I end up with the same amount of indices as when I started.

In my imagination, it's like the other nodes don't know they should be deleting the indices, so they fill up the called node with their copies of the data ... or something.

Does anyone know what's happening?

Configs:

```
cluster.name: intra-1
node.name: intra1
marvel.agent.enabled: false
http.max_initial_line_length: 65kb
transport.tcp.port: 9300
http.port: 9200
http.max_content_length: 500mb
node.master: true
node.data: true
discovery.zen.ping.multicast.enabled: false
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.enabled: true
discovery.zen.ping.unicast.hosts: ["intra2", "intra3"]
network.bind_host: "0.0.0.0"
network.publish_host: _non_loopback:ipv4_
```

The two other nodes have `intra1`, `intra2` and `intra3` alternating.

Comment: Can you show your indices and elastic search configurations

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you seen the logs in three of the clusters and can you try the below mentioned command

curl -XGET 'http://localhost:9200/_cat/indices?v'

It will give you the list of indices that you have created then delete the all indices using this query

curl -XDELETE 'http://localhost:9200/*'

Comment: I actually don't know what happened, but I changed the configuration to `index.number_of_replicas: 2` and `index.number_of_shards: 1`, to maximize availability, deleted all data and logs folders, set `ES_HEAP_SIZE to 2g`, and reindexed, and everything started acting normally... Very strange...

Comment: Ya  at last you did that one but first and fore most you need to go for logs and analyze what the issue was then we can act based on the logs provided.Always re installation is not the feasible way.